# The length of shortest curve dividing topological sphere into two parts of same area

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, spherical-geometry, metric-geometry

$(S^2,g)$ is a  Riemannian manifold, where $S^2$ is homeomorphic to the 2-dimensional sphere. And the area of $(S^2,g)$ is $4\pi$. $\gamma$ is the shortest curve dividing $S^2$ into two parts of equal area. Denote the length of $\gamma$ as $L(\gamma)$. Then, how to show
$$
L(\gamma)\le 2\pi
$$
I just feel it is right. But I don't know how to prove. If the proof is complex, tell me the reference is enough, thanks.

PS(2023-7-24): Please don't click the close. The example of psl2Z is not a counter-example,  mollyerin have explain it.

Comment: When you write "$S^2$ is homeomorphic to the unit sphere" you're implying that the only structure of defined on $S^2$ is a topological space. Then the notion of area and length are not defined in $S^2$.

Comment: @jjagmath  Thanks, I add a Riemannian metric on it.  If need,  $(S^2,g)$ can be smooth Riemannian manifold.

Comment: Isn't it wrong in general? For example if you glue two unit squares $[0,1]^2$ along the boundary and denote it by $M$, then you have a topological sphere $M \cong S^2$ with area $2$. But every curve dividing $M$ into two parts of the same area has length $\geq 2$, because if the curve is inside one square it has to be the boundary curve of this square, so has length $4$. Otherwise it has to connect two boundary points in each square, so has length $\geq2\cdot 1 = 2$.

Comment: @psl2Z If you normalize this example to have area $4\pi$ then your bound becomes $L(\gamma) \geq 2 \sqrt{2 \pi}$, which is not good enough for a counterexample (unless I am mis-computing).

Comment: @mollyerin yes, you are right. Then, maybe, it is true... Maybe the standard $S^2$ is the extreme case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the metric admits a fixed-point-free involution, your estimate is equivalent to [Pu's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pu%27s_inequality).  Otherwise this seems to be open, unless I am overlooking some recent literature.  An estimate can be found in

> Papasoglu, Panos.
> Cheeger constants of surfaces and isoperimetric inequalities.
> Trans. Amer. Math. Soc. 361 (2009), no. 10, 5139–5162.

Comment: There is a later paper by  Allais, Simon.  Improvement and generalization of Papasoglu's lemma. Grad. J. Math. 3 (2018), no. 1, 31–36.  But the estimate is still not optimal.

Comment: Thanks, it really be crazy.  I didn't think it would be an open problem since it looks pretty intuitive.  I need time to understand Pu's inequality.  Besides, what is the metric of fixed-point-free involution ?

Comment: @lanse7pty, if you have a fixed-point free involution on the 2-sphere which preserves the metric, then you can define the quotient metric on the quotient real projective plane.  Pu's inequality relates the systole of that metric and its total area.

Comment: So bad, I feel most metric can't satisfy it. it is too strong.  The Papasoglu's paper I saw it a while ago. At that time, on topological sphere, I guess for the Cheeger set $\gamma$ there is $\int_\gamma K ds\le \frac{4\pi L(\gamma)}{A}$, where $K$ is sectional curvature, $A$ is the area of topological sphere. I feel this inequality maybe useful to deal the dividing. Do you know analogous inequality ?

Comment: $L(\gamma)$ is the length of $\gamma$.